# Why am I receiving an ElementClickInterceptedException error?

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, web-scraping

The question on the survey asks: What days of the week are you consistently available? I would like to check Sunday.

I am duplicating the code I see from an online video, however, I am receiving this error. Some people are suggesting that a pop-up may be blocking the program from working correctly but I do not see a pop up.

I have tried using chromedriver and geckodriver. The error is present in both.

The code to see if Sunday is selected works properly:

```
status=driver.find_element_by_id("RESULT_CheckBox-8_0").is_selected()
print(status)
```

output:

```
False
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="my_webdriver_path"\\chromedriver.exe

driver.get("https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?1537702596407")
```

What days of the week are you consistently available?

I would now like to check the Sunday box. Here is my code:

```
status=driver.find_element_by_id("RESULT_CheckBox-8_0").click()
    print(status)
```

I would like the Sunday box checked but I am receiving this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <input id="RESULT_CheckBox-8_0" class="multiple_choice" name="RESULT_CheckBox-8" type="checkbox"> is not clickable at point (313,599) because another element <label> obscures it
```

I do not see another element that obscures the program. Does anyone have any suggestions? I am new to coding so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Text `Sunday` is a label for this checkbox and it may hide checkbox so it is not clickable. You could try to click this label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is related to the same values that are being used for different attributes in the *label* and *input* tags.

As you can see the 'for' attribute of the label has the same value as the 'id' attribute (wich doesn't allways have to be a unique value) of the  eventhough you are using 'find_element_by_id'.

To fix this you could use a different locator like XPATH. You can get a xpath by right clicking on the element (when you are inspecting the code with f12) and than select [copy] - [xpath]

Here is some code that should work (note: I have placed the chromedriver.exe in the same location as the .py file it self):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?1537702596407')
status = driver.find_element_by_id("RESULT_CheckBox-8_0").is_selected()

if status:
    pass
else:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='q15']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/label").click()
```

Don't forget to eventually close the driver, otherwise it  will stay in de background as a running procces.

You can do so by:

```
driver.close()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try use `ActionChains` to click the element.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("RESULT_CheckBox-8_0")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
status = driver.find_element_by_id("RESULT_CheckBox-8_0").is_selected()
print(status)
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

Answer (score 2):

To `click()` on the *checkbox* with text as **Sunday** you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?1537702596407")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[starts-with(@for, 'RESULT_CheckBox-') and contains(., 'Sunday')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Sunday]

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you sir @DebanjanB! =)